# Creating new instance of control loses reference?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a devexpress chart control from a designer

```
chartControl1
```

Then I pass this control to one of two classes

```
DailyChart(chartControl1, id)
```

In the class I do some magic ;)
But then at a runtime I need to present second chart in same control after combobox selection changes.
So it goes like

```
WeeklyChart(chartControl1, id)
```

But it doesnt restore chartControl's state, and the control doesnt have Reset function or anything like that. Found an advice to create new instance

So I do:

```
chartControl1 = new ChartControl()
chartControl1 = WeeklyChart(chartControl1,id)
```

But then I cant see any result
I start with DailyChart, works fine
Then do new instance and call WeeklyChart and I can see still DailyChart, but then button which were doing some actions on the charts doesnt do anything - it seems like the chart lost reference? Why is that and how to fix it?

IMO when assigning new instance to chartControl1 I shouldnt break reference, and after passing it to another class it should just reset all settings in this control

Comment: show your code for the button click

Comment: All you did was change the object reference.  Now you have two chart objects.  One that your charControl1 variable references, and the original one that the user is still looking at.  You'll have to dispose the old one and add the new one to the Controls collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't work like that.

If `chartControl1` is created from designer and in code you set the variable to a new `ChartControl` instance then from then on it will point to that new instance, *not* the instance that was originally created.

I'm not very familiar with DevExpress chart control but I'm pretty sure you can programmatically make any changes you want in it. Ask on their [support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/), I'm sure someone can help you with that there.